# How to detect whether request to a URL from a system is made through a browser or through a software/malware

Tags: malware, web-browser

I am using FortiAnalyzer-VM64 v6.4.2 GA build2122. Many requests are logged in my firewall/UTM log that are to malicious websites. Although these requests are blocked by the UTM, the problem is that I am having trouble investigating whether these web requests are made through a browser or there is some malware sitting in the systems that is trying to establish connection. I don't see any user-agent field in the web filter of my firewall/UTM log. Kindly help.

Comment: User agents can easily be spoofed, so that this would be pointless. I'd focus on the time between requests, with the exception of resources such as javascript and css files that are being loaded from the initial request. But if a lot of 'main' requests are made in a specific amount of time one could conclude whether this is a bot or a user.

Comment: But a bot can also mimic the timing constraints to fool the administrator into thinking that a user made those requests. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely correct. By using random sleep's after each request, one could mimic user behavior programatically.

Answer (score 4):

Short anwser: you cannot be sure of the origin of the request. Full stop.

Long answer: genuine browsers add headers to help site to identify them because they offer extensions over the standard for HTML and Javascript and want to allow the server to user them. It also helps sites to support multiple versions of the browsers including older ones that would not support the last versions of Javascript.

Poorly written bots will forget to set a valid user-agent header, and you can easily detect them. But nothing prevent them to pretend being a valid browser and sending exactly the same headers in the same order. I often do that to automate tests against a web application: I first run the tests *by hand* using a browser and look at the headers, and then I code those headers in my test script.

You can try to detect *bursts* of requests because scripts can run much faster that a user can type or click.  But scripts can add *pseudo random* timers in order to send the requests more or less the same a human user could do - I seldom do that in my tests, only to test the part that tries to detect bots... even if I do know that it will not detect all of them ;-)

Comment: One comment here: you cannot do that using **network** controls, but you can do that using **host** controls, like EDR solutions

Comment: @Alex: Could you please elaborate? How can EDR tools differentiate requests coming from a genuine browser from requests forged by scripts? And are even they targetting this question?

Comment: Sure. From my experience, any modern EDR solution should provide the visibility of network connections performed from or towards the host. Of course, it has certain limitations - but overall, you should be able to see which process has made certain connection towards proxy, DNS, or external host - whether it was system, any legit application, or a suspicious one. The amount of events is quite big, so building a detection rule over it is quite challenging - but it works quite well for detection & triage purposes.

Comment: @Alex: And how could the **server** know what the client did? The question is not how to detect illegal operations on  a client system *from that client system*, what an EDR indeed targets. It is about how the server can differentiate a request coming from a browser from a request coming from a script

Comment: Well, I understand that very well, that's why I didn't propose that as an answer. Yes, the topic starter mentioned UTM, and it is probably implied that he is trying to use UTM only - however, that restriction was never mentioned explicitly in the question. The only point of my comment was: you can't detect that from outside the host, so if you really need it, go with host-based solution like EDR

Comment: @Alex: thank you for your last comment, it is now much more clear... And it made me learn a bit more on modern EDR ;-)